# Python Get variable outside the loop

Tags: python, variables

I have a python code ,i need to get its value outside the for loop and if statements and use the variable further:

My code:

```
with open('text','r') as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
      if 'hi' in line
         a='hello'

print a  #variable requires outside the loop
```

But i get `Nameerror: 'a' is not defined`

Comment: you have to set the variable `a` outside the loop

Comment: a = None or a = "" before with line.

Comment: You missed  colon in the __if__ line.

Comment: @Murillio4 Not necessarily; there's only one scope in the posted code, but `a` is not guaranteed to be set by the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message means you never assigned to `a` (i.e. the `if` condition never evaluated to `True`).

To handle this more gracefully, you should assign a default value to `a` before the loop:

```
a = None
with open('test', 'r') as f:
   ...
```

You can then check if it's `None` after the loop:

```
if a is not None:
   ...
```

Comment: great but i dont want to print if its None what should i do for that?

Answer (score 3):

You may also try:

```
try:
    print a
except NameError:
    print 'Failed to set "a"'
```

EDIT:
It simultaneously solves the problem of not printing **a** , if you did not find what you were looking for

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here are correct—you need to guarantee that `a` has been assigned a value before you try to print it. However, none of the other answers mentioned [Python's `for ... else` construct](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), which I think is *exactly* what you need here:

```
with open('text','r') as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
      if 'hi' in line:
          a='hello'
          break
  else:
      a='value not found'

print a  #variable requires outside the loop
```

The `else` clause is only run if the `for` loop finishes its last iteration without `break`-ing.

This construct seems unique to Python in my experience. It can be easily implemented in languages that support `goto`, but Python is the only language I know of with a built-in construct specifically for this. If you know of another such language, please leave a comment and enlighten me!

Answer (score -2):

just define `a=null` or `a=0`
so a become global variable and you can access a in anywhere in your code