# How to access a local variable outside for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to access a variable defined inside an if statement in a for loop, outside the for loop. but I am getting the 'Unbounded Local Error'

I have tried assigning `lambdaPriceUsWest2 = None` as suggested  here:
[Python Get variable outside the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406399/python-get-variable-outside-the-loop)

Also, tried specifying `global lambdaPriceUsWest2` inside if statement with `lambdaPriceUsWest2 = None` before the code snippet.

```
for x in range(len(response['PriceList'])):
        priceList=json.loads(response['PriceList'][x])
        if priceList['product']['sku'] == 'DU9X9ZR8C8DYH3Y9':
             lambdaPriceUsWest2= priceListpriceList['product']['sku']['USD']

        if priceList['product']['sku'] == 'CVE47QZ9RSF8DTEM':
            lambdaPriceUsEast2= priceListpriceList['product']['sku']['USD']
            break

logger.debug(lambdaPriceUsWest2)
```

Expected Result:
0.055512 (similar value)

Actual Result :
Error:

```
"errorMessage": "local variable 'lambdaPriceUsWest2' referenced before assignment",
  "errorType": "UnboundLocalError"
```

Comment: The variable is only assigned to conditionally.  If none of the items in the pricelist have that specific SKU, the variable never gets defined.  Initialize the variable before the loop, to whatever value you want it to have in such a case.

Comment: Initializing outside the loop as ```lambdaPriceUsWest2=""``` and ``lambdaPriceUsEast2=""``` I am getting a value for lambdaPriceUsWest2 as expected but blank for lambdaPriceUsEast2

Comment: why don't you just iterate over actual items instead of getting the length, making a range and finding items by index? ex. for price_list_json in response['PriceList']

Comment: @PooyaMobasherBehrooz but that doesn't help either

Comment: @KshitijJaju I know that, I was trying to make your code more readable, but to help you fix the problem, are you sure you have these data on your data source? and also remove break lines from your code, loop will stop after it reaches break, so if the UsEast variable gets found first, it won't look for the UsWest one anymore.

Comment: @PooyaMobasherBehrooz Got that! Yeah initializing outside the loop and removing break does the job. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best way is before the for loop try to initialize that variable. For example:

```
lambdaPriceUsWest2 = ""
```

Comment: This is helping me half way, I have two variable to get outside for loop,```lambdaPriceUsWest2``` and ```lambdaPriceUsEast2```
Initialized both outside the loop and I am getting a value for ```lambdaPriceUsWest2```  but blank for  ```lambdaPriceUsEast2 ```

Comment: if one of the if statement is valid one of them will be replaced by the variable in the if and the other one doesn''t change from the first initialization

Comment: So how do I replace both because both the statements are valid

Comment: try to remove the break after the second if statment

Comment: Yup, that fixed it!, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

just defined a var outside loop and update it value

```
local_val =''
for x in range(len(response['PriceList'])):
        priceList=json.loads(response['PriceList'][x])
        if priceList['product']['sku'] == 'DU9X9ZR8C8DYH3Y9':
             lambdaPriceUsWest2= priceListpriceList['product']['sku']['USD']
             local_val = lambdaPriceUsWest2

        if priceList['product']['sku'] == 'CVE47QZ9RSF8DTEM':
            lambdaPriceUsEast2= priceListpriceList['product']['sku']['USD']
            break

logger.debug(local_val)
```

Comment: This is throwing the same error ```local variable 'lambdaPriceUsWest2' referenced before assignment"```

Comment: You cannot use ```lambdaPriceUsWest2``` to access it, use ```local_val``` to access the value

Comment: Yeah, using ```local_val``` and ```local_val2``` but getting the error for ```lambdaPriceUsWest2``` on the same line

Answer (score 0):

First of all, declare a variable before assignment (inside the for-loop) using 'global' syntax like this:

```
global lambdaPriceUsEast2
```

Then assign any value you want for it, for example:

```
lambdaPriceUsEast2 = priceListpriceList['product']['sku']['USD']
```

It's worth mentioning that if you don't assign it to any value, it's still be undefined outside the loop. Because functions in python are references to objects. To avoid this, you can assign it to None before any conditions::

```
global lambdaPriceUsEast2
lambdaPriceUsEast2 = None
```

This will do the work. You can also check all global variables using built-in globals() function.

But using global statement is still not the best practice. I'd suggest you writing a function and returning the value like this:

```
def get_price(price_list):

    for x in range(len(price_list)):
        priceList=json.loads(price_list[x])
        if priceList['product']['sku'] == 'DU9X9ZR8C8DYH3Y9':
            return priceListpriceList['product']['sku']['USD']

        if priceList['product']['sku'] == 'CVE47QZ9RSF8DTEM':
            return priceListpriceList['product']['sku']['USD']
     return None
```

value = get_price(response['PriceList'])